# Java Garbage Collector Logic Query

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage

A quick question about the Java Runtime Garbage Collector.

Take this scenario:

***Two Objects both hold a reference to the other.
No other Objects hold any reference to these Objects.
The Objects are not doing anything - they're not Runnables, if they are their threads have ended.***

Would the Garbage Collector collect these objects, because I'm using these Objects in massive amounts and 'disposing' of them by cutting references... but are they really being disposed?

Comment: Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366211/what-are-the-roots

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910194/garbage-collection-in-java-and-circular-references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the elements are eligible for collection. See:

[What are the roots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366211/what-are-the-roots)

Whether they will be collected or not is up to the garbage collector.

Comment: Ah, so if I can't access them, they'll be collected? Or at least that's the idea I get from that page?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that the garbage collector operates on its own schedule. Objects can hang around for a long time. The only guarantee is that they'll be collected before you get an out of memory error.