# Is an object garbage if it is referenced only from garbage?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Suppose there is an object a of class A, which holds a reference to another object b of class B. And this is the only reference to b. So now, if all references to a is removed, then a is ready to GC. Does this mean that b is also ready to get garbage collected? because, though b has a reference ( inside a ), it is unreachable, because a is unreachable.

So how exactly does this scenario works? I mean the order of garbage collection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Garbage Collection in Java and Circular References](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910194/garbage-collection-in-java-and-circular-references)

Comment: Its better to think of the garbage collector figuring out what **isnt** eligable for garbage collection and collecting the rest. If it can be seen from the root then it isnt eligable

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Once an object is unreachable from a root, it will be collected. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6366211/24874) for an explanation of GC roots.

Entire subgraphs will be collected (as you describe) presuming no node within that subgraph may be reached.

Java (and .NET) use *mark and sweep* garbage collection which deals with this kind of problem.

Reference count-based systems (such as C++'s `std::shared_ptr<T>`) may fail in the case of circular dependencies that remain unreachable. This is not a problem for Java/.NET GC.

Comment: If there is one downvoter who downvotes for no reason, then there are other people like me who upvote for a good answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Java GC is smart enough to collect islands of isolated objects though they maybe pointing to each other. Hence, `b` also becomes eligible for garbage collection. The point to note here is that although you have a reference to `b` it's not *live* in the sense that it cannot be reached from your program's root.

Comment: This good or else a circular reference (A has a reference to B and B to A) could never be collected but could also be unreachable

Comment: Seems like somesones down voting a lot of the good answers in this question. Some people are just like that

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the GC. A JVM can be told to use different GC's and typically uses 3 GC's as one (eden, copy, markcompact).

In any typical GC *and* in refcounting the situation *you* described is handled cleanly, both objs are collected. Think of it in 2 stages: first "a" gets noticed and collected then "b" gets noticed and collected. Again: the specific means of noticing depends on the GC.

Comment: It's my experience that refcounting fails if you have circular references. That is, if A->B and B->A, both have a count of one, yet neither is reachable.

Comment: There is no reference from "b" to "a" in what the OP described.

Comment: True, but if I'm not mistaken your answer didn't take that emphasis before your edit. At any rate, GC is a huge topic that OP is apparently new to and we may be getting away from the introductory aspects :)

Comment: @DrewNoakes my answer has not been edited maybe you saw the one 2 minutes before mine (Ravi's answer)

Answer (score 0):

Even if the objects reference internally to each other, and they do not have a reachable reference from program, they will be eligible for GC. THere is a good explanation with diagrams here

http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/22/how-do-objects-become-eligible-for-garbage-collection/

Answer (score -1):

That is exactly the point of GC. Since b is unreachable from main thread, it will be garbage collected. It is not just the count that matters.