# Java Does Nested Class Instance Prevent GC of Outer Class

Tags: java, oop, garbage-collection

Assume `Outer` is instantiated somewhere, and after a while there are no references to it. Does the implicit reference in `inner` to the `Outer` instance prevent GC from running, or does the is it a "special" reference?

```
public class Outer {
    private class Inner extends Something {}

    private Inner inner = new Inner();
}
```

Comment: If an object tree is not reached form GC root it will be the subject of GC. In your sample it is.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366211/what-are-the-roots/28057186#28057186

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the instance of `Outer` is not reachable from a GC root, the reference to an `Inner` instance in your example code will not stop the garbage collector from freeing the memory the `Outer` used.

Consider this diagram:

```
Stack of main thread           public static void main(String[] args) {
         |                       Outer outer = new Outer();
         v                     
       Outer<--\
         |\    |
         v \---/
       Inner 

Stack of main thread               outer = new Outer();
         |
         v          
       Outer<--\
         |\ new|
         v \---/
       Inner 

       Outer<--\                   // a reference to the Outer from the Inner
         |\ old|                   // doesn't change the fact that the Outer
         v \---/                   // can't be reached from a GC root.
       Inner                       // Thus the old Outer is eligible for collection (dead)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, since there are no references to `Outer` besides for one from "inside" itself, it is eligible for GC?

Comment: Not quite, it is eligible for GC under the assertion you made in your question *"and after a while there are no references to it [`Outer`]"*

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I should have been more explicit.