# Java garbage collection scenario

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I was going through the `Java` Garbage Collection process and different scenarios in which `GC` is applicable.

Below is the scenario I am confused about :

```
List<X> listX = new ArrayList<X>();

    for(int a = 0;a<100;a++){
        listX.add(new X(a));


    }

    for (X xObject : listX) {
        xObject.printValue();
    }
```

In the first loop I am adding the new objects in each loop and in the latest loop I am just printing the values, so, are those objects which I am adding in the list applicable for `GC`?

What does this sentence mean ?

"One more excellent example for when an instance can become eligible for garbage collection. All the properties of an instance can be stored in the register and thereafter the registers will be accessed to read the values. There is no case in future that the values will be written back to the instance. Though the values can be used in future, still this instance can be marked eligible for garbage collection"

Comment: It highly depends on the given scope of the variable and the scope of the surrounding list I would say. The entries of your list are still referenced by your list, so that by themself they aren't applicable for gc.

Answer (score 9):

No, they're not, since they're referenced by the array which is referenced by the ArrayList whose reference is in the stack of the current thread:

```
thread stack --> ArrayList --> array --> x1, x2, x3, etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

The lifetime of the objects you add to the list is related to the lifetime of the `list` itself, because from what I see from the code, `listX` is the only object holding references to `X` objects.
So, `X` objects will be collected when `listX` is not referenced any longer. 
Check [@JBNizet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33258502/822588) to see how they are actually referenced or connected (+1). Always think like this, how my objects are connected and if they still referenced all the way back to [GC Roots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366211/what-are-the-roots), and remember `Java` is smart, it doesn't do [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) :)

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the following code, changed it up a bit.

```
List<X> listX = new ArrayList<X>();

    for(int a = 0;a<100;a++){
        X tmpX = new X(a);
        X unusedX = new X(a);

        listX.add(tmpX);
}
```

When the new keyword is called, a new object is created on the Heap. This means in this example, it will create a `tmpX` and a `unusedX`. You are adding the `tmpX` to the array, therefor meaning it has a reference in the `ListX`. When it's garbage collection time, the garbage collector will check for objects there only live in the current iteration of the for scope, defined by the {} brackets. `unusedX` will be collected, but since `tmpX` will have a reference in the list, it is kept on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection only frees memory held by objects that are no longer strongly reachable from any root, for instance in the case of circular dependencies. The references to each of the new `X` objects are held in the `List` and so they won't get garbage collected.

Comment: That's incorrect. Objects that are still referenced can be GCed if they're not strongly reachable from any root anymore. That what allows circular dependencies to be GCed: A -> B and B -> A.

Comment: Well, sounds like I don't know as much about garbage collection as I thought I did... Could you elaborate as to why it's wrong/which parts are wrong, @SleimanJneidi?

Answer (score 0):

No, if this piece of code is reachable, if not it will be illegible. The garbage collector will look for objects which aren't being used any more, gets rid of them and free up the memory.