# Meaning of icons in HPROF Viewer in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-memory, heap-dump, hprof

From time to time I use the Memory Monitor and HPROF Viewer in Android Studio to check for any memory leaks and memory usage in general.

I believe I know the meaning of most symbols and colours used in the Viewer, but I would like to be sure and not just have my own understanding of them. I haven't found any explanations on web, but I'm sure the answers to my questions are pretty straight forward.

What do the follwing symbols in the reference three mean?

1: [image: Symbol #1]

2: [image: Symbol #2]

3: [image: Symbol #3]

4: [image: Symbol #4]

5:[image: Symbol #5]

What does it mean when the font colour of the instance is blue, red, bold or italic ?

Sometimes the symbols 1, 2 and 3 can be combined in the same instance. Does that mean something special?

6: [image: Symbol Comb]

7: [image: Symbol Comb]

My feature request for the HPROF Viewer is a tooltip when hovering the different icons..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What do the follwing symbols in the reference three mean?

1. The dominator icon
2. A gc root icon (*1* & *2* icons definitions can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-memory.html#treeroot))
3. `F` stands for `Field` (see JetBrains' [icons reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/symbols.html))
4. Object

> What does it mean when the font colour of the instance is blue?

Here's you can find a font-colors schema: [What do the Android Studio HPROF reference tree element colours represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35674959/android-studio-hprof-viewer/37127420#37127420)

> My feature request for the HPROF Viewer is a tooltip when hovering the different icons..

Passed to Android-folks. Not sure it'd help though.